# What's the function of insult in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

Out empire is debating about the meaning of insult, we know that it will reduce the opinion of our rival empire but we wounder what's the application of insulting rivals?

Is it good to push other rival to attack us or declare war on us?

Are there other applications or side effects for insulting?

Comment: It makes me feel good.

Answer (score 11):

Mechanically, insult is at the moment nothing more than a temporary -100 opinion modifier, which may possibly goad an empire into attacking you, but it's unlikely to work unless it's a fallen empire.

Roleplay wise, it is of course a method to show somebody you really don't like them.

The function of insult was greater in other Paradox games, so I suspect it will be expanded upon in later patches/dlc (e.g. in EU4 it gives a casus belli and provides power projection)

Comment: Unable to verify this immediately, but for some reason I thought there was also some influence gain from it. I'll have to double check it though, it's been a bit since I used it so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Dulkan but does having really low reputation in their eyes push them to declaring a war on you? basically can you "provoke" them into a war and comme off as the legitemate party to other's eyes?

Answer (score 0):

When at war, with a low rep, issuing a ‘insult’ command will promp the enemy ships into combat.  Unsure if it works at all times, but I’m finding the pattern to be the same, insult a warring faction that -for a moments time- is not attacking and they will say something like ‘now you’ve done it’ and send all of their ships to bombard you.

Comment: When you are at war, enemy ships will already attack your ships on sight and try to attack your systems.

Comment: I wonder if this answer is to goad a fleet into attacking that might not actually be ready and/or potentially being threatened/distracted by something else. More testing/evidence is needed IMO.